# index out of range error for two pandas series that should be basically the same

Tags: pandas, if-statement, drop

```
a=cosmos.isna().sum()
c=len(cosmos)
a=a/c*100
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i]>80:
        cosmos.drop(columns=cosmos.columns[i], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

index out of bounds error the a and cosmos.columns should basically have the same length.
i am trying to drop some columns. but it shows
IndexError: index 7 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 6
i specifically mentioned axis=1 i don't know what it has to do with axis 0

i have no idea what to do i just want to drop all columns with more than 80 percent empty rows.
so i could do it one by one this time. i tried doing it all again but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're having is likely due to the fact that you're dropping columns inplace. As you iterate, the dataframe `cosmos` gets shorter, yet you index those columns using the original integer index i. As a rule of thumb, you should avoid modifying a dataframe (or any sequence in general) while iterating that same object.

That aside, there are better panda-esque solutions that take (or drop) the relevant columns in one operation, which avoids iterating all together. Here is one:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
cosmos = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
    "b": [np.nan, 3, 4, 7, 5, 3, 2, np.nan, 1, 2],
    "c": [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 6, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    "d": [np.nan] * 10
})

# Use .mean instead of .sum, which avoids the `/ len(df)` step
nan_pct = cosmos.isna().mean()

cosmos = cosmos.loc[:, nan_pct <= 0.8]
```

which uses a boolean mask to select only those columns where less than 80% of its values are nan.

Comment: yeah i didn't think about it thanks